# Working out users points - update vs select

Tags: mysql, performance, sum, database-performance

I have users who earn points by taking parts in various activities on the website and then the user can spend these points on whatever they like, the way I have it set up the at the minute is I have a table -
tbl_users_achievements and tbl_users_purchased_items

I have these two tables to track what the users have done and what they have bought (Obviously!)

But instead of having a column in my user tables called 'user_points', I have decided to display their points by doing a SELECT on all achievements and getting a sum of the points they have earnt, I am then doing another select on how many points they have spent.

I thought it might of been better to have a column to store their points and when they buy something and win stuff I do an UPDATE on the column for that user, but that seemed like multiple areas I have to manage, I have to insert a new row for the transaction and then update their column where if I use a query to work out their total won - spent I only have to insert the row and do no update. But the problem is then comes to performance of running and doing a calculation with the query.

So which solution would you go with and why?

1. Have a column to store their points and do an update
2. Use a query to work out the users points they can spend and have no column

Answer (score 0):

myself, I would put the user points into a separate table PK'd by user ID or whatever and store them there and do updates to increment or decrement as achievements are attained or points spent.

Answer (score 0):

Your current model is logically the right one - a key aspect for RDBMS normalization is not to repeat any information, and keeping an explicit "this customer has x points" column repeats data.

The benefits of this are obvious - you have less data manipulation code to write, and don't have to worry about what happens when you insert the transaction but can't update the users table.

The downsides are that you're running additional queries every time you show the customer profile; this can create a performance problem. The traditional response to that performance problem is to de-normalize, for instance by keeping a calculated total against the user table.

Only do that if that's absolutely, provably necessary.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is we have a banner at the top of the page displaying the username and their points, which means every time the page changes it has to run the query again, I was possibly considering storing the value into a session or a cookie and updating when a record has changed, but that causes the same problem with having to do another update, just this time through PHP and not MySql. While we're still a small site right now I guess it's not a problem, I was just thinking somewhat in the future on the performance.

Comment: Well, then you might want to define "better" in your question - there are many ways to approach that qualification. In general, though, if performance is your main issue, it's better to cache outside the database - CDN, application cache, query cache, that sort of thing.